# Coercing GLMs into list

Tags: r, function, return, lm

I'm writing a function that produces 3 different models as output and want the function to return all three models so the user can see the output. Currently I am using something like:

```
    return(FinalLM,LMReduced1,FullLM)
```

and lets say I do the call of the function:

```
    Test<-ExampleFunction(Input)
```

I want to be able to see:

```
    Test$FinalLM
    Test$LMReduced1
    Test$FullLM
```

to see the different models and what's inside like:

```
    Test$FinalLM$aic
```

etc etc.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question title is basically the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return(list(FinalLM,LMReduced1,FullLM))
```

Comment: You'd think this would be the case, but with the list(M1,M2,M3) it loses the linear model properties and I can only call the 'Test' output as a whole. It doesn't allow for Test$M1 or Test$M1$aic

Comment: @ASavage Add names then: list(M1 = M1, M2 = M2, M3 = M3)

Comment: You just made my day. Thank you!